# AngularJS 'A' directive with null templates copy tags to DOM

Tags: templates, angularjs, directive

For my project, I have a requirement for directives to be defined that do not modify the DOM, and also do not leave artifacts of their existence in the DOM. I seem to be unable to make this work with AngularJS.

Consider these examples:

```
<div empty-arg="some-param"></div>
<div null-arg="another-param"></div>
```

With associated directives defined as follows:

```
var module = angular.module( 'component', [] );

module.directive('emptyArg', function() {
    template: '', 
    replace: true, 
    scope: false, 
    link: function() { // ... }
};

module.directive('nullArg', function() {
    template: null,
    replace: true,
    scope: false,
    link: function() { // .... }
};
```

After compilation, I want the resulting DOM elements to look like this:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

But the absence of a template seems to cause AngularJS to ignore the replace request, leaving the resulting DOM elements looking like this:

```
<div empty-arg="some-param"></div>
<div null-arg="another-param"></div>
```

How can I force AngularJS to get rid of these attributes in the post-compile DOM?

A jsFiddle demonstrating this can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vankirkc/ezN3M/34/

Update:

It is possible to delete the created attributes after they are created, but what I am really looking for is some way to leverage the template definition parameter to intercept the creation of the DOM element such that it doesn't copy this directive across. It appears this isn't possible in version 1.0.3.

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you want no trace of it?

Comment: The template will have a lot of arguments to define attributes of a given element. Copying them across is going to consume a lot of memory, and in a memory constrained environment like a phone, this is a bad thing.

Comment: I still don't follow. Copying them across what? They're already in the DOM before the directive ever runs. What are the directives going to actually do? You could use comments instead of attributes, perhaps.

Comment: They're in the dom in collapsed form.

Comment: Imagine a scenario like this:

'<container>'
'   <row ng-repeat='item in items' arg1='' arg2='' ... arg100='' />
'<container>'

The argN directives are needed to modify each item, but their markup isn't needed after the ng-repeat row, so I'd rather they don't show up. Not a perfect example, but this is the idea.

Comment: But ngRepeat will automatically update on changing data, so the args will continue to be needed, no?

Comment: Note that in your fiddle the link functions in your directives will be ignored because there is a compile function. "link: ... This property is used only if the compile property is not defined." -- [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: I still don't see how this can work. If you remove the attributes (as the answer by @MarkRajcok will do) then you can't use any of the attributes to change the DOM - compile is pre-DOM manipulation. And I don't think you can use them in an ngRepeat anymore.

Comment: @Josh, Christopher did say post-compile didn't he... oops.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: My understanding is that compile is broken into two phases, pre-link, which occurs prior to dom manipulation, and post-link, which occurs after the link function has already done its business with the attributes. Mark's fragment looks like a winner.

Comment: @Josh, only the template requires the tags. The output rows of an ngRepeat should not. My preference is that when the new dom elements of the ngRepeat are created that the attributes aren't copied over. I suppose that's too much to ask. It's also a little weird to have a template parameter that is ignored in the attribute case if it's null or empty, but used otherwise.

Comment: @ChristopherVanKirk The ngRepeat duplicates itself using a different isolate scope to create each element. Your directive gets its elements from the DOM. Once they're in the DOM - i.e. your template can use them at all - then they are already copied. In order to remove them, you must sacrifice performance to manually delete what was already there. That's why I said this didn't make a lot of sense to me. 

But I'm not sure what you meant by the ignored parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually "empty-arg" and "null-arg" are just normal attributes of DOM element, AngularJS is using them to mark which directives to apply at element.

So it would be actually bad, if one directive will remove attributes from DOM element. For example - it is possible to write another directive that will use this attributes to modify its behaviour: in different AngularJS libraries you can see, that controls use `ngModel` attribute to get expression on which element is been bound.

And also as those attributes are already present at DOM tree, deleting them will cause DOM tree modification and can imply performance issue.

If still you actually whant to delete those attributes, you can try to modify second argument of linking function:

```
attrs.$set('empty',undefined);
```

But generally I would not recommend to do so: you *can* save some memory (but I am not sure that it would be saved - I think it should be benchmarked), but you'll get bigger loading time as DOM tree would be modified.

But anyway [here is Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gGzy2/) to demonstrate that it is possible.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "controls use ngModel attribute to get expression on which element is been bound" means. Well, I know what it means but I don't understand the relevance of the statement to this question.

Comment: Let me give an example: I've created an directive for some very custom validation and used 'ngModel' attribute for getting model expression to be able to validate it. And if some another directive remove this attribute from element, my directive wont be able to get model expression (unless I save it to directive's scope), but that is not a good place to store.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all attributes, you can do it in the compile function:

```
for(var i=0; i < tElement[0].attributes.length; i++){
    tElement.removeAttr(tElement[0].attributes[i].name)
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/qYpBJ/).

**Update:** as @Josh pointed out in a comment, removing the attributes will essentially make this a run-once-only directive, and none of the attributes will be available in the link function, making this answer a non-answer/non-solution.

Comment: This isn't quite right. I don't want to remove all attributes, I want to remove on the attribute of the directive, and its parameter string, if any. The idea is good though. I'll give it a shot.